# Android:Playing bigger size audio wav sound file produces crash

Tags: android, audiotrack

I am trying to **play the bigger size audio wav file(which is >20 mb)** using the following code(AudioTrack) on my **Android 1.6 HTC device** which basically has **less memory**. But i found device crash as soon as it executes reading, writing and play. But the same code works fine and plays the **lesser size audio wav files(10kb, 20 kb files etc)** very well. 
P.S: I should **play PCM(.wav) buffer sound**, the reason behind why i use `AudioTrack` here.

**Though my device has lesser memory, how would i read bigger audio files bytes by bytes and play the sound to avoid crashing due to memory constraints.**

```
private void AudioTrackPlayPCM() throws IOException
{
    String filePath = "/sdcard/myWav.wav"; // 8 kb file

    byte[] byteData = null;             
    File file = null; 

    file = new File(filePath);

    byteData = new byte[(int) file.length()];

    FileInputStream in = null;

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream( file );
        in.read( byteData );
        in.close(); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int intSize = android.media.AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT);     

    AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, intSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);        

    at.play();

    at.write(byteData, 0, byteData.length);         
    at.stop();

    at.release();
}
```

Could someone guide me please to play the AudioTrack code for bigger size wav files?

Answer (score 0):

Your intSize will be the minimum buffer size needed to init the AudioTrack, try using a multiple of this to create a bigger buffer

```
AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000, 
AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, intSize*10, 
AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```